# UFT giving error while using descriptive programming

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

My script is working normally but when i am using function & descriptive programming its giving me result failed without any proper result.

Attaching error screenshot:

[image: Attaching screenshot]

**Script**

```
systemutil.Run "www.tokri.com/siteadmin"

executefile "C:\Users\tusha\Documents\Automation\Automation\Function_library\Tokri_Function\tokri_class.qfl"

Set oh = new tokri

oh.tokri_webedit("Tokri Login" , "username" , "xyz")
```

**Function**

```
Class tokri
    'WebEdit Function
    Function tokri_webedit(br,we,v)
        If Browser("title := "&br).Page("title:="&br).WebEdit("name:="&we).Exist Then
            Browser("title := "&br).Page("title:="&br).WebEdit("name:="&we).Set v
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass , "Success", "Data Entry Successfull"
        else
            reporter.ReportEvent micFail , "Fail" , "Object Identification Unsuccessfull"
        End If
        tokri_webedit = "Data Entered Successfully In Textbox"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Set oh = new tokri.. not able to get that.. could you explsin some. If you eant to create object. U can use          set oh = descrition.create. if u want to creat object atleast define some properties of that object. Without properties qtp wont be able to indentify object and you will get error.

Comment: You Cannot create the class object in actions, you have to create the class object inside the class and return it. See this Link http://automated-chaos.blogspot.com/2008/06/qtp-and-four-ways-of-creating-classes.html.

Comment: Try this - In the library file.

Function oh
 set oh = New Tokri
End Function

Then set the object for oh in your test like 'set abc = oh'